# How does access to Overwatch get enabled?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike-go-overwatch

I've clocked up over 500 hours on CS:GO, and recently I've had access to [**Overwatch**](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/overwatch/) to review cases of reported cheating and disruptive behavior.

In game it shows as **Overwatch Beta**. Is this something new that is being rolled out to certain users or is it due to my playing time (500 hours) crossing a threshold to have access to it?

The linked blog states:

> **How do I become an investigator?**
>
> Currently, the best approach is to play lots of matches in our official Competitive Matchmaking. We are slowly adding players to the pool of investigators, and randomly pick them with consideration to their playtime and skill level. The goal is to invite as many skilled reviewers as possible.

From this I guess I've been randomly selected, but was curious about whether 500 hours was part of the selection criteria.

Comment: I have also heard that you need 150+ competitive wins. One of my friends recently got access to Overwatch after passing this landmark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've done some more research on the topic based on what is stated on the [**Overwatch FAQ**](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/overwatch/):

> **How do investigators get selected?**
>
> Investigators are selected based on their CS:GO activity (competitive wins, account age, hours played, Skill Group, low report count, etc.) and, if applicable, prior Overwatch participation level and score (a function of their accuracy as an investigator). Community members who maintain both a high level of activity and high Overwatch scores will receive more cases to elect to participate in.

From my investigation, the common scenario for people getting selected to participate is **150 competitive wins**, which I passed a few weeks ago before being added to Overwatch.

With regards to hours of game time, I had just over 500 hours when it was enabled, but I don't believe this is the boundary. There probably is a minimum number of hours, but I think it is less that 500 as people on [this thread](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/overwatch_official/discussions/0/540732596785315853/) have stated:

> ...had neither 500 hours nor AK+ ranks. I was Nova 2 when I got overwatch. [Ursus](http://steamcommunity.com/id/ursoos)
>
> If it helps I got mine directly after 150 MM wins, at master guardian elite rank and just shy of 400 hours played in steam. [.Johan #silverkrigarn](http://steamcommunity.com/id/rudelius)
>
> Got overwatch , gold nova 3 , 374 hours and 162 wins. [Captain C. Caliber](http://steamcommunity.com/id/cptcruiser)

[neffer_23](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/42093/neffer-23) stated in [his comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223253/how-does-access-to-overwatch-get-enabled#comment-303087) that it needs to be 300+ hours, which sounds plausible but I can't verify that.

I'm currently Gold Nova 2, so perhaps the skill group needs to be Gold Nova at least.

I do play regularly and honestly I'm not that great so I would assume that I have a very low report count. I very rarely do anything worthy of someone suspecting me of cheating.

Also I've never had any bans, I guess that would definitely be a black mark against your name.

Comment: I'm MGE with 433 hours and my access was enabled at exactly 150 competitive wins. This is the better answer in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I would assume so, yes.

From [their blog post](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/overwatch/)

> Currently, the best approach is to play lots of matches in our official Competitive Matchmaking. We are slowly adding players to the pool of investigators, and randomly pick them **with consideration to their playtime** and skill level. The goal is to invite as many skilled reviewers as possible.

According to [steamdb](https://steamdb.info/app/730/graphs/), the average playtime is  179.5h. With this (I'm unsure how accurate that figure is), you're in the higher part of playtime, thus your playtime was most likely considered.

Comment: I can't remember where I read this, but Over watch is unlocked at Gold Nova Rank, with 150 wins and 300+ hours. not to mention a clean account(no reports or many kicks)