# CSGO Cooldown system reductions after more than one 7 day ban? Do bans affect getting overwatch?

Tags: pc, counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike-go-overwatch

I get cooldowns often. I kill teammates, yeah, I'm that guy. That might be why I'm so low ranked(GN2) anyway, I understand first time banned 30 mins then an 2 hours and so on and so on.

I got a cooldown for a week everytime now and I have been for the last few month, I usually play a few days before I get a cooldown. I have been getting consistent cooldowns and want to know how long it will take before I get back down to a 1-day cooldown?

Will it go straight down in one week or will it take the few months I have been getting the bans for? Also I'm gold nova 2 and have 160 wins, do bans affect if/when I get overwatch? (Sorry about my English, I am English just not the best at English, some things might not make sense)

Comment: related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223253/how-does-access-to-overwatch-get-enabled

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your offense level goes down 1 rank for every 7 days you do not get banned. This only counts over time you could actually play. With out knowing what your offense level is it is impossible to figure out how long it will take for you to get rid of your offense levels. You can read a full post about it [here](http://steamcommunity.com/app/730/discussions/0/624075036318156108/).

Second up is Overwatch membership. As far as I can find there is no correlation between being a griefer and obtaining membership in Overwatch. I do however know that membership in Overwatch is not an automatic thing once you get a certain number of matches/wins completed. You also have to be good at reporting people appropriately in a match. ie: You have to report someone for hacking in a specific manner and then it has to be verified by Overwatch that you reported it correctly.

Comment: related to the Overwatch part: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/223253/how-does-access-to-overwatch-get-enabled